# How to make my bot send messages in announcement type channel discord?

Tags: discord.js

How to make my bot send messages in announcement/news type channels in Discord? Ive tried nearly everything and still I cant make it work.

All i need is to send messages via announcement channel with a command!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like for people to assist you with coding issues, you must prove that you are trying to understand how to fix the issue you are facing. You did not include enough detail for people to assist you with the code or with the concern, make sure to state it better next time.

If you simply want the bot to announce something right after you type the command, you can create a const to look out for the channel, such as the following:

```
const announcementChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name ==="announcements");
```

After that, you can set up your desired message either by letting the bot grab what you say, or setting up a predefined message for it, such as an embed or a simple text.

In order to get the message to be sent to the specific channel, you can just do it by typing the following:

```
announcementChannel.send('This is the announcement!');
```

Since we created the variable `announcementChannel`, we are telling the bot to send the embed/message to this channel.

I hope it was helpful.